# Comparaison bteween laravel and symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to know, which projects or companies currently use Symfony or laravel.
for example drupal project use symfony....
 i'm going to do a comparaison between them.
please help me!!
Thanks!!

Comment: This sort of question is really not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Consider fixing the typo in your title and pasting it into the search bar of your favorite search engine.  Then sit back and start reading though the several thousand posts on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony => [Symfony projects](https://stackshare.io/symfony)
Laravel => [Laravel projects](https://stackshare.io/laravel)

Comment: for you what's the better for design an application web